# WPF Xaml Change TextBox Trigger Change Foreground

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

I have a TextBox style. I am trying to make a Placeholder(I realized I am not the first to ask about this.)  However I found a very uncomplicated way that works for my needs.  Once the user clicks in the box the "email" is removed.

```
    public  void email_input_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if(email_input.Text == "email")
        {
            email_input.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Now for the font. My default text color is grey.  I would like this to turn Black when the user starts typing.  I am new to xaml and wpf and cannot figure out the trigger to do so.

```
    <!-- Placeholder -->
    <Style x:Key="PlaceHolder" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="340"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.5"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="PreviewMouseDown" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Property="PreviewMouseDown" is not recognized or not accessible.  Why is it not accessible, and what trigger can I use instead?

Edit: This seemed to work, though I'm not sure how robust.

```
public  void email_input_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(email_input.Text == "email")
    {
        email_input.Text = "";
    }

    email_input.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
    email_input.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;            

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"/>
</Trigger>
```

`PreviewMouseDown` is not a property, its an event, which is why you are getting the message. `IsKeyboardFocused` is a property that should accomplish what you want. For a list of properties, see [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx#Properties).

Note: This will also set the text back to grey once the user has left focus. If this is not what you want, let me know and I'll update this answer.

Comment: great thanks, how do I keep these Properties once the TextBox is no longer in focus?

Comment: I would like it to stay black.  Much like login in pages using HTML5

Comment: when the window it first initialized

Comment: @Mwspencer If you only want it to be gray when it is initialized, then you could set the foreground color to black in your `email_input_Click` event.

Comment: Thanks took some time to find the right Property I was looking for.  (FontWeight).  If someone were to write a book comparing HTML to XAML I would be one of the first to purchase :)